# Android fetch all music files And display in the list

Tags: android, amazon-ses, alan

I am having difficulty in importing music files in android. Problem is: I want to get all the music on the phone, but it doesn't work, only some of them are coming.

Hello, I am having difficulty in importing music files in android. Problem is: I want to get all the music on the phone, but it doesn't work, only some of them are coming.Why not coming ?

```
val arrayList: ArrayList<AudioModel> = ArrayList<AudioModel>()
val projection = arrayOf(
    Audio.Media._ID,
    Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    Audio.Media.DURATION,
    Audio.Media.SIZE
)
val selection = Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME +
        " >= ?"
val selectionArgs = arrayOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).toString())
val sortOrder = Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"

val cursor: Cursor? = activity?.contentResolver?.query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    sortOrder
)

val idColumn = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Audio.Media._ID)
val nameColumn = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
val durationColumn = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Audio.Media.DURATION)
val sizeColumn = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Audio.Media.SIZE)

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
    val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
    val duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn)
    val size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn)
    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id
    )

    // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
    // that represents the media file.
    arrayList.add(AudioModel(contentUri.toString(),name,duration))
}
```

Comment: Which files do come? Which files do not come?

Comment: `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).toString()` Please tell the value of that string.

Comment: Hi . Just Music Files Coming. But Not All

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.